# Vue basic starting

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

Im trying to learn Vue , and I just started on mac, installed it with terminal,made new folder,opened it in sublime and this is my code, but when I opet in browser , still it doesnt work. Why? 
    Do I have to install something more?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vueboze</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <input type="text" name="input">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>

    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>

  </body>


  <script>

    let data = {
        message: 'Hello World'
    };

    document.querySelector('#input').value = data.message;  

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your query selector is looking for an element with `id="input"`. You don't have one. Also, nothing you're doing here is actually using Vue.

Answer (score 0):

you just forget the atribute "id" for tag "input",

`<input type="text" name="input" id="input">`

you can learn the basic documentation in https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Thank you veru much, I know what Im doing now:)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here. Could you please create a JSFiddle of your issue? From what I can tell, you're not initializing your Vue.js application. Unless it's happening in build.js. Still, without more details, it's hard to assist. Are you getting an error? If so, what is there error and where are you seeing it?

I will say that I've created a [Vue.js training course](https://ecofic.com/courses/vue-getting-started/) if you're interested in getting started.